# add property for ellipse to get on mouseevent c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm adding ellipses in a long for cycle (more than 100 is added), and I want to know a property added in the same for cycle on click event.
inside the for cycle:

```
 var ellipse = new Ellipse();
 ellipse.myValue=12; // this needs to be editable and working
 ....
 ellipse.MouseDown += ellipseClick;
 canvas2.Children.Add(ellipse);
```

Here is the listener:

```
private void ellipseClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if(myValue==12) 
        ....
    }
```

of course it is a bit more complicated, I'd need a pointer or 3 int values for every Ellipse.
I don't want to go on every Ellipse and check the click position and if it is the same as the sender. 
I can't extend the Ellipse class, because it is sealed, and I can't rewrite code in the Ellipse class.

Comment: I really don't understand what exactly your question is...

Comment: ellipse.myValue won't compile because it doesn't contain 'myValue'. I would extend Ellipse class so it would contain, but I can't because it is a sealed class. I want to have additional info (myValue) for my click event.

Comment: @csomakk: You're looking for [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Tag`-property, to store additional information.

```
ellipse.Tag = 12;
```

I hope that is what you are asking for, but according to your comment on my question, you just want to store information with each ellipse.

You can create a struct or class that contains all the information you want and just set the `Tag` to that class. It allows you to store about anything you want.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can store anything you want. Just create a class with all the information needed and add this to the tag.

Comment: awesome! i didn't thougth the Tag is not a string but any object. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem, Tag is actually a `object`. You should go through all the answers and accept one as the most useful one to your question, since StackOverflow is in a way based on that.

Comment: its so elegant: ellipse.Tag = new EllipseExtension { i = 10, dir = i };

Comment: It is actually an inelegant holdover from Windows Forms. In WPF we use [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) instead. They are far more robust and support a wider range of problems, and better yet they are strongly typed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Tag` property, but general purpose tags are a hangover from the days of winforms. Read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx). What I do not like Tags is that they are not typed, which means casting to read from it, and they have no meaningful name. An alternative is:

**Attachment property**

It's hard to write, byt luckily VS has a snippet type `propa` and press tab.

So:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SO_AttachmentProperty
{
    public sealed class EllipseAttachments
    {
        #region Field1
        public static int GetField1(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (int)obj.GetValue(Field1Property);
        }

        public static void SetField1(DependencyObject obj, int value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(Field1Property, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Field1.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Field1Property =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Field1", typeof(int), typeof(EllipseAttachments), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
        #endregion

        #region Field2
        public static int GetField2(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (int)obj.GetValue(Field2Property);
        }

        public static void SetField2(DependencyObject obj, int value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(Field2Property, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Field2.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Field2Property =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Field2", typeof(int), typeof(EllipseAttachments), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Then use the properties like so:

**In code**

```
var ellipse = new Ellipse();

//write
EllipseAttachments.SetField1(ellipse, 123);
EllipseAttachments.SetField2(ellipse, 456);

//read
var f1 = EllipseAttachments.GetField1(ellipse);
var f2 = EllipseAttachments.GetField2(ellipse);
```

**Attachment properties come into there own in xaml**
Note the local namespace.

```
<Window x:Class="SO_AttachmentProperty.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO_AttachmentProperty"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse local:EllipseAttachments.Field1="789" local:EllipseAttachments.Field2="67"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Tag property which holds object. You can put there anything you want, you can create your class which can hold any number of values. You can do something like this.

```
var ellipse = new Ellipse();
ellipse.Tag=12;



private void ellipseClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Ellipse ellipse = (Ellipse)sender;
    int value = (int)ellipse.Tag           
    if(value==12) 
    ....
}
```

Comment: Tag is object so you can put there anything you want, just cast it before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom control which contains an ellipse and handles the mouse over in a unified fashion. Provide the ability within the custom control (a dependency property of all the other controls maybe) to know about the other ellipses and get the sender info as needed.